# Magento 2 store locator extension to use custom table data

Tags: magento2.2

We are looking to implement store locator and came across Amasty and other store locator extensions. Those extensions appear to be creating custom tables during install and give admin panel pages to create, update, and maintain existing and new stores. 
We are looking for is a store locator extension/module, that can work with existing DB table(s) data, without minimal code changes and/or configuration, to avoid changing other processes that rely on existing DB schema/tables. Let me know if there are any paid or open source extensions that allow this kind of flexibility.

The existing table has lot of columns that are used during custom checkout process, would not like to change that flow to limit testing and development effort for the store locator pages alone.

Thanks